# GCP MySQL raw connection string

Tags: mysql, asp.net, google-cloud-platform, mysql-connector

Please I need your assistance on how to connect to mysql 8.0 database on GCP.
I hosted my ASP.NET core web API on Heroku and I want to connect to my database on GCP from Heroku but I am finding it difficult.  Below are different connection string I have tried;

```
"Server=<INSTANCE-IP>;Uid=<DB_USER>;Pwd=<DB_PASS>;Database=<DB_NAME>;AllowUserVariables=True;"

"server=<INSTANCE-IP>;database=<DB_NAME>;uid=<DB_USER>;pwd=<DB_PASS>;port=3306;AllowUserVariables=True;"

"Server=/cloudsql/<Connection name>;Uid=<DB_USER>;Pwd=<DB_PASS>;Database=<DB_NAME>;Protocol=unix;AllowUserVariables=True;"
```

Also, I had the web API and mysql database hosted differently because I needed to gain more knowledge on how it works. I am completely new to this. Please can anyone help figure out what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you try to include  "SOCKET_PATH": "/cloudsql/{connection_name}" to see if that works from web api where you are trying to create a connection ?

Comment: I have tried that also and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Your connection string to Google Cloud SQL should have the following format, which is similar to what you had tried but not quite:

```
Server=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;Database=DB_NAME;Uid=USER_NAME;Password=PASSWORD
```

Using this structure you should be able to connect to it, if not than the problem is like to be elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for your nice response @Rafael Lemos. Let me check this out now

Comment: But I'd like to ask, is this pwd=<DB_PASS>; and Password=PASSWORD the same? Are they case sensitive stuffs going on here?

Comment: I don't think they are case sensitive tbh, but use password instead of pwd.

Comment: I tried out the connection string and keeps throwing an exception when the connection is about to open. MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.'

MySqlException: Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Comment: Try adding the port to the IP of the server or adding `Port=3306;` to the string.